# Scilab, add text to an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, scilab

I would like to add text in an image using Scilab; at first I wanted to use SIVP imshow, but it turns out this function does not return a handle. IPD's ShowImage on the other hand does return a handle, so I thought I could just do :

```
sceneImgFigure = ShowColorImage(sceneImg,"Scene");

for k=1:size(inspectedScene)
    uicontrol(sceneImgFigure, ...
              "style", "text", ...
              "string", mtlb_num2str(inspectedScene(k).alocated_label), ...
              "position", [inspectionModel(k).centroid(1) inspectionModel(k).centroid(2) 20 20], ...
              "fontsize",15, ...
              "BackgroundColor",[0.9,0.9,0.9]);
end
```

But using uicontrol I use graphic coordinates, not image coordinates, which result in the text being displayed at the wrong place. Beside, ShowImage crop the image. Here what I get :

[image]

I can't find any relevant answer on Scilab's help, so I'm kind of stuck here. There is a [way](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1BALJ/) to do what I want in Matlab, but the code seems to be impossible to translate to Scilab (no text nor getframe function in Scilab, to begin with...).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve this (just in case it may be someday useful to someone) :

```
ShowColorImage(sceneImg,"Scene");
for i=1:size(inspectedScene)
    xstring(inspectedScene(i).centroid(1)-5, ...
            size(classDispImg,1)-inspectedScene(i).centroid(2)-5, ...
            mtlb_num2str(inspectedScene(i).alocated_label));
    e = gce();
    e.font_size = 1; 
    e.font_foreground = color(0,0,0);
end
```

Which gives :

[image]

I got part of the solution from Scilab users mailing list. As said by xenoclast, I figured I had to scale the coordinate in y, using image height.

Answer (score 1):

I use `xstring` to put annotations onto plots according to the plot coordinate system. Depending on the format of your base image you might be able to use `imageplot` (from the SIVP I think) to draw the image, in which I believe image pixels map to plot coordinates.

```
xstring(inspectionModel(k).centroid(1), inspectionModel(k).centroid(2), mtlb_num2str(inspectedScene(k).alocated_label))
```

If you can't use `imgplot` you may have to manually scale all the coordinates. It isn't as bad as it sounds - if you know the size of your image you can work out scale factors for your coordinate system. I did something like this so I could put axes onto an `imageplot` when doing spectrograms using the wavelet toolbox.